# Парсинг одинаковых тегов python

Tags: python

Учусь парсингу, хотелось бы узнать как парсить одинаковые теги.
Есть фрагмент кода HTML:

```
<a class="item hot" href="/item/4246896245-188530139-AK-47%20%7C%20Redline%20%28Field-Tested%29/">
<div class="imageblock">
<div class="image" style="background-image: url(https://cdn.csgo.com//item/AK-47%20%7C%20Redline%20%28Field-Tested%29/100.png);"></div>
<div class="price">976 <small></small></div>
</div>
<div class="name" style="color: #000000;">
AK-47 | Красная линия (После полевых испытаний)
</div>
<div class="i-inscribed"><img src='https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/apps/730/icons/econ/stickers/broken_fang/badge_of_service.c298fc7632c932412a7820b766107d1d292df0ba.png' title='Наклейка: Медаль за заслуги'><img src='https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/apps/730/icons/econ/stickers/skillgroup_capsule/mge.6bd7c33a9839980d92db1148351abc0f7d25e571.png' title='Магистр-хранитель — Элита'><img src='https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/apps/730/icons/econ/stickers/skillgroup_capsule/mge.6bd7c33a9839980d92db1148351abc0f7d25e571.png' title='Магистр-хранитель — Элита'><img src='https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/apps/730/icons/econ/stickers/broken_fang/badge_of_service.c298fc7632c932412a7820b766107d1d292df0ba.png' title='Медаль за заслуги'></div>
```

Мне нужно вывести все значения из 'title', но когда я пытаюсь это сделать у меня выводится только первое значение из 'title'

Как сделать чтобы выводились все?

```
        url = 'https://market.csgo.com/?t=all&fst=-1&sd=desc'
        r = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        items = soup.find_all("a", {"class": "item hot"})
        for item in items:
            # for i in s1mple:
            #     s1 = s1mple.find('img')['title']
            item_url = item.get("href")
            item_title = item.find_all('div', class_="name").text.strip()
            item_price = item.find_all("div", class_="price").text.strip()
            price = float(item_price.replace(' ', ''))
            stickers = item.find_all('img')
            for sticker in stickers:
                print(sticker.img['title'])
```

Comment: Вашу версию кода в студию

Comment: r = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        items = soup.find_all("a", class_="item hot")
for item in items:
        sticker = item.find('img')['title']
        print(sticker)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну примерно так

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

url = 'https://market.csgo.com/?t=all&fst=-1&sd=desc'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
items = soup.find('div', class_='market-items').find_all("a")
for item in items:
    item_title = item.find('div', class_="name").text.strip()
    item_price = item.find("div", class_="price").text.strip()
    print(item_title)
    print(f'   {item_price}')
    for nak in item.find_all('img'):
        print(f"   {nak['title']}")
```

ответ

```
AK-47 | Красная линия (После полевых испытаний)
   976
   Наклейка: Медаль за заслуги
   Магистр-хранитель — Элита
   Магистр-хранитель — Элита
   Медаль за заслуги
AK-47 | Красная линия (После полевых испытаний)
   1 042.98
   Наклейка: Тер-тех
   Kjaerbye | Атланта 2017
   Убийца
   Легендарный беркут-магистр (голографическая)
....
```

Comment: Не выводит все равно(

Comment: по одному выводит также

Comment: что дали тем и работаем.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Я изменил, сейчас посмотрите пожалуйста, только начал учиться не судите строго пожалуйста

Comment: @Dmitriy лучше ссылку на сайт и что вам еще извлечь

Comment: вы серьезно?Ну если серьезно сейчас скину

Comment: Обновил ответ, смотрим оцениваем. :)

Comment: Спасибо большое, вы просто гений

Comment: "Я не волшебник, я только учусь" х/ф "Золушка"(1947)

Comment: Извините что беспокою), у меня возникла еще одна проблемка, не могли бы вы помочь?

Comment: Можем перейти в какую-нибудь соц сеть чтобы я описал проблему по подробнее?

Comment: в какую соц сеть?

Comment: ну не знаю в какую вам удобнее

Comment: ну телеграмм на пример.

Comment: да, давайте в телеграм

Comment: как мне вас найти?

Comment: https://t.me/Bum_Bok